# How does the Search Predicate of Findall work in a generic List

Tags: c#

I am able to work with the findAll and it's predicate...but I am wondering about the mechanics that makes it work.

```
 List<BradCollection> b = myList.FindAll(SearchForMe);


List<BradCollection> SearchForMe(string str)
 {

  if (str.Contains("brad"))
    return true;
  else
 return false;
}
```

where is the "str" argument  in the SearchForMe obtained?

Comment: return type should be bool, not List<>

Comment: I am confused by your code. Is this is a list of strings, or a list of BradCollections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking; perhaps a look at a simplified implementation of FindAll would help.  This isn't how FindAll is actually implemented but it is close enough to understand what's going on:

```
public delegate bool Predicate<A>(A arg);
...
public List<T> FindAll(Predicate<T> predicate)   
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (T item in this)
        if (predicate(item))
            result.Add(item);
    return result;
}
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is obtained from `myList` which likely implements `IList<string>`, which inherits from `IEnumerable<string>`. It enumerates each item in `myList` and then the generic parameter is passed to do the predicate.

If you look, there is the `<T>` generic parameter on the `Predicate`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx